# Alter views results in a hook

Tags: views, 8, hooks

When I use contextual filters in a view, I can select an option to display a summary when the argument is not present. If I do it, it shows a list of node IDs instead of titles. For example, I get the following output, where the first number is the node ID, and the second number is the count of nodes.

- 1256 (12)
- 4323 (723)
- 5643 (34)

I want is to rewrite the output and replace the node ID with its title. `ViewExecutable` has a `$args` property I can check to know when the argument is not present.

How could I achieve this in a hook? In Drupal 7 I could use `hook_views_post_execute()`. I modified `$view->result` and changed it on my own.

I tried to do the same with Drupal 8 and the same hook, but `hook_views_pre_render()` gets a `ViewExecutable` object, and I don't know how to change it. I used the following code.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'myidoftheview') {
    $results = $view->result;
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      \Drupal::logger('myview')->notice('<pre>'.print_r($result,TRUE).'</pre>');
      // What code should I write here?
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) { ...`. Next install Devel and the Devel submodule Kint. Then you can `ksm($result)` to print out vars. (Don't click the plus icon in the output, click only titles.)

Comment: Check other `hook_views_pre_render()` sample snippets on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/8.2.x

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. Prior to put this question I have tried to find a solution. I have read drupal 8 views api, and some snippets examples, but all of them (I have found) change title, image style or similar. Neither of this examples are for change the values. On the other hand, I don't think this is a duplicate of the question that Neograph734 are indicating. I have read this question prior to post my question and as I understood it is for change the title.

Comment: @briast, your question is how to alter `$view`, which is exactly what the other question is about. Yes, the demonstrated alteration is indeed editing the title, but there is much more to edit. Please update your question to include what you want to edit in your results. I have to admin that I initially did not see you were already using the same hook.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more precise. I hope it was clear enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to alter results just setting the view result property within `hook_views_pre_render`. My code looks something like:

```
$results = $view->result;
$filteredResults = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
  if ($result->_entity->field_somefield->value === 'somevalue') {
    $filteredResults[] = $result;
  }
}

$view->result = $filteredResults;
$view->total_rows = count($filteredResults);
```

Comment: This solution would not help to rewrite the result. This is just filtering out some of the results.

Answer (score 1):

View hooks like `hook_views_pre_render()` should be placed in an execution.inc file within the module directory: `mymodule.views_execusion.inc`

The execution order of View hooks is as follows:

1. hook_views_pre_view
2. hook_views_pre_build
3. hook_views_post_build
4. hook_views_pre_execute
5. hook_views_post_execute
6. hook_views_pre_render
7. hook_views_post_render

[Read what these hooks do here](https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/overview-drupals-view-execution-order)

The following is a good example for Drupal 8.x|9.x. Your goal is to create a new result set of entities and set it to `$view->result`. It is important to set the index property so the results will render properly.

Slightly altered from @rosemarystanley

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function HOOK_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {

  $results = $view->result;
  $filteredResults = [];

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result->_entity->field_name->value === 'fieldValue') {
      $filteredResults[] = $result;
    }
  }

  // Important to set index values for view results rendering
  foreach ($filteredResults as $key => $row) {
    $row->index = $key;
  }

  $view->result = $filteredResults;
  $view->total_rows = count($filteredResults);
}
```

Comment: It's important to set index values when using views bulk operations.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your result stores. It can be like entity with relation or just field:

1) `$result->_entity->set('field_Name', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');`

2) `$value->node__field_Name = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';`

Comment: What about global field ?